# If the sequence $(x_1)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ converges to n as $i \to \infty$ for n in reals, does $x_ix_{i+1}$ converges to $n^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I encountered a problem asking to prove if the sequence $(x_i)_{i=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $n$ as $i \to \infty$ for n in reals, does $x_ix_{i+1}$ converges to $n^2$?

Please don't give me the full answer but if someone could tell me if that is true and some small clue of how to prove it I would really appreciate!

Comment: Yes, its true. What you are trying to prove is that $\lim a_n\cdot \lim b_n=\lim a_nb_n$ provided both limits exist. Best clue I can give is to start with the $\epsilon$ definition of the limit and recall that if $a_n$ approaches some $L$ then it is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you mean $(x_i)_{i=1}$. Notice that $\lim_{i\to \infty}x_i=n$ and $\lim_{i\to \infty}x_{i+1}=n$ and use/prove the limit law for products.